# Need to validate NGINX incoming Headers with or without values

Tags: bash, nginx

Trying to check if both request headers with value or without value i should allow the incoming connection. So i have written a script for that.

But it is not working when both headers with empty value.

> It is responding with error code **415**

```
location / {
    set $test "00";
    if ($http_x_token){
       set $test "1";
    }
    if ($http_api_version){
       set $test "${test}1";
    }
    if ($test = "00"){
       return 415;
       break;
    }
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
}
```

Anything i am missing in this script?

Answer (score 0):

An empty header field-value is not valid per RFC7230.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

The field-value is not optional and must be specified.

So nginx doesn't distinguish missed and empty header.

PS: break directive doesn't make sense in code snippet below:

```
if ($test = "00"){
   return 415;
   break;
}
```

https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return

`return` stops processing and returns the specified code to a client.